# Tablerates csv, When I upload csv it shows error

Tags: magento2

I want to import table rates csv, when I uploaded a csv it shows error :

```
The file "/tmp/opt/lampp/temp/php7efXy3" doesn't exist
```

why? where I am doing wrong can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be the folder in which you are uploading not exists, thats why this error shows.
Check weather this folder exists or not, is not then create.

Please try this.